# Select ID where Table Row Count = 1

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple.

I want to return a column value (id) from a table person where the count of rows in persons = 1.

So something like :

```
SELECT Person.Id
FROM (select Count(*) from Person Having Count(*)=1);
```

But its not working.. Any help much appreciated.

Joe

Comment: Could you rephrase that as a requirement or higher-level question: your english explanation is basically speaking in SQL.  You seem to be saying you want to select the ID of a person, where there is only one person?  What if there are two?  It makes little sense so some more background will help us answer this.

Comment: It's worth adding that most of the answers are assuming your Person table might have duplicates with the same Id - which is obviously bad.  I'd hope that that's not what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks Kieren, no there won't be duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select person.id from person where ((select count(*) from person) = 1)
```

you'll get null if the the table is empty, or has more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
select id from (
  select p.id, count(1) cnt 
  from Person p
  group by p.id
)
where cnt = 1
```

homework? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've left the GROUP BY out:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) FROM Person
GROUP BY ID
HAVING (COUNT(1) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find duplicate ID's?

```
SELECT ID FROM Person p1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person p2 WHERE p1.ID = p2.ID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select Person.Id 
FROM Person
group by Person.Id
having count(*) =1